# Playing a real time video stream from iPhone camera on a 20 second delay

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, video-streaming, avfoundation

I am trying to see if it is possible to record a video from the iPhone's camera and write this to a file. I then want the video to start playing on the screen a set time after. This all needs to happen continuously. For example, I want the video on the screen to always be 20 seconds behind what the camera is recording.

Some background:
I have a friend who is a coach and would like for his players to be able to see their last play. This could be accomplished by a feed going to a TV from an iPad always 20 seconds behind what is recorded. This needs to continually run until practice is over. (I would connect the iPad to the TV either with a cable or AirPlay to an Apple TV). The video would never need to be saved and should just be discarded after playing.

Is this even possible with the APIs AVFoundation offers? Will the iPhone let you write to a file and read from a file at the same time to accomplish this? Any other better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to a file, how about saving your frames in a circular buffer big enough to hold X seconds of video?

The way I would start to do this would be to look at what's provided in [`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009544) and its delegate methods (where you can get the frame data from).

Comment: I'm just worried about memory management. Do you think I would be able to hold that amount of frames in RAM? Also, how do you go about playing those frames out of the buffer as a normal video? Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: You can probably do things to help shrink the amount of memory you need to buffer, like reduce the size of the frame or resolution.  As for playing those frames out of the buffer, you could either write the last X seconds from that circular buffer out to a file (which you could then open via AVAsset's `assetWithURL:`) or you might be able to create something from the buffer directly via `AVAssetReader`. I'm not 100% certain, having never done exactly what you're trying to do myself.  :-)